# Can you initially change the value <input :value="data" /> in a component?

Tags: vue.js, v-model

Hello I'm technically new to vuejs and I was wondering if I can change a value of <input **:value="{data: data}"** />
so in my main page template

```html
<titled-input 
  width="528" 
  height="49.6" 
  fontSize="16" 
  title="Event Title" 
  :data="title"
>
</titled-input>
```

and in my main page script

```js
export default {
  components: { 
    PrimaryButton,
    TitledInput,
    InputTags,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      title: "Title",
    };
  }
};
```

and in my components.vue (not its real name) I added a

```js
:value="{data: data}"
```

and also in the props I added

```
data: String,
```

I thought this might work because other props work fine especially when I add a width: Number in the props
and

```js
:style ="{ width: width + 'px'}"
```

do this

When I tried the code above it will give me

[image]

what I am expecting inside the input field is the word "Title"

Comment: You can use event emitters to send data from child component to parent component. https://vuejs.org/guide/components/events.html

Comment: @Amini I'm sorry but how can I do that for my input field? Woudn't v-bind be a faster way?

Comment: I'm making a sandbox template for you.

Comment: @Amini I actually found the answerr!!! I just needed to make :value= "data" instead of :value="{data:data}"

so like v-bind is actually one way, you can still share your other way tho because it might help me on the way of my coding journey :>

Answer (score 1):

in your components.vue, you need to replace `:value="{data: data}"` with:

```js
:value='data'
```

Comment: it doesn't work, the output will be {Object: object} so i used :value="data" instead and it worked

Comment: Looks like this answer has been edited to reflect the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

So I found the answer. I changed the syntax from `:value="{data:data}"` to `:value= "data"`